# Delete duplicate rows in Oracle SQL, leaving the latest entries

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, sql-delete

I'm using the following SQL to identify duplicates in the table 'transaction_list'. This works perfectly. Now I want to delete all duplicates from that table based on these criteria and leave only the latest entries. These can be identified by the column 'last_update'. I tried different DELETE statements but it didn't work. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

```
SELECT par_num
,tran_num
,COUNT(*) AS num_duplicates
FROM transaction_list
WHERE last_update >= to_date('01-mar-2020 00:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy 
hh24:mi:ss')
GROUP BY par_num
,tran_num
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY par_num
```

Comment: What's the significance of 1st March in your sample code? Do you specifically want that date and time, or are you just trying to use `last_update` as a tiebreaker when deciding which `par_num / tran_num` duplicate to delete?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using the row ids:

```
delete from transaction
where 
    last_update = date '2020-03-01'
    and rowid in (
        select rid
        from (
            select 
                rowid rid, 
                row_number() over(partition by par_num ,tran_num order by last_update desc) rn
            from transaction                
        ) t
        where rn > 1
    )
```

The subquery generates the list of row ids for rows that are not the latest in their group (ie all records having the same `par_num ,tran_num`) - the most recent record per group is identified using `row_number()`. The outer query just deletes those rows.

Comment: Thanks, but it throws the error: ORA-00904: "RN": invalid identifier

Comment: @Skywalker: sorry I forgot to give `row_number()` an alias. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If the idea is to delete all `par_num` / `tran_num` duplicates except the last in each set ordered by `last_update`, then this should do it:

```
delete transaction_list
where  rowid in
       ( select lag(rowid)
                over (partition by par_num, tran_num order by last_update)
         from   transaction_list );
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6bdc143d138409589b2e10f1a232be4c)

Explanation: [`lag`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LAG.html) returns a value from the previous row (or another earlier row - you can specify all kinds of offset logic if you want, but here we just want the previous row). The [`over()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html) clause specifies the ordering and windowing. In this case, we want to order each set of  `par_num` / `tran_num` combinations by `last_update` and delete the previous row. The `partition by` section means the ordering resets for each `par_num` / `tran_num` combination, so each group has a 'last' row that won't be deleted.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. Can you pls explain how lag(rowid) and partition by work? I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: Added explanation.

Comment: Thanks, mate, really appreciated! Very clear and concise. Just to fully understand, what's the purpose of ORDER BY, and is that only optional here?

Comment: The `lag` function requires an ordering so that it knows which is the previous row. (Looking at my answer again I realised I’d left `par_num` and `tran_num` in the `order by` clause where they weren’t needed. Hope it’s clearer without them.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, William! Wish all here were explaining like you:-)