# How to keep only the first unique element and delete its duplicates in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

So this query looks like a very easy by its statement but in actual isnt that easy. 
Heres my code what ive tried.

```
Delete from table where id
In (select id from (select 
 id, row_number() 
  over(partition by id) 
rn from table where rn>1)
```

The above can work but thats not standard sql for almost all databases like partition by may not be supported in most of the other databases. What i was trying was below is it possible using group by. I tried below but i am not sure this will work or not. Any suggestions and which one is optimized

```
  //using group by    
Delete from table where id
In (select id from(select 
 id from table 
  Group by id 
  Having sum(1)>1) 

  )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete duplicate rows in Oracle SQL, leaving the latest entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60836201/delete-duplicate-rows-in-oracle-sql-leaving-the-latest-entries) ('First' vs 'Latest' is just a matter of ordering.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As question says

> delete its duplicates in oracle

then

```
delete from your_table a
where a.rowid > (select min(b.rowid)
                 from your_table b
                 where b.id = a.id
                );
```

Comment: thanks that too helped corelated subquery always being efficient but just wanna know will rowid work for all versions

Comment: You're welcome. It will work in all versions of Oracle. I don't know other DBMS so I can't tell whether they have ROWID or not.

Comment: I assume almost all RDBMS have some kind of ROWID, however the name could be different. For example, SQLite uses `ROWID` but it is an integer. MongoDB uses `_id`, etc.

Comment: Yeah i wanted something more generic so likewise asked. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` as follows:

```
Delete from your_table t
Where exists (select 1 from your_table t1
Where t1.id = t.id
And t1.rowid > t.rowid)
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, i knew exists is better to use than In. But Does rowid work in all versions

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja, why are you concerned about the ROWID? Even if the ROWID format would change with every Oracle version it would work anyway.